# How to fast connect my XMPP based app like WhatsApp?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, whatsapp

I am playing with Smack API and Openfire. I found, In XMPP protocol you have to open stream, log in and enable features for every time,which is very time consuming. Then how the famous massager app WhatsApp work, how it can connect in so less time? If anyone can give me any hint please. I want to make like that, For that i can customize both the Openfire and Smack.

Thanks and sorry about my English.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up your connections considerably by utilizing optimizations, such as Stream Management (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html) and Roster Versioning (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0237.html) - both of which are supported.

Comment: Stream management works  till connection time out ...I want fast reconnection like whatsapp